# Attaching financial value in itself, to several options contained within MS Access Combo Box?

Tags: ms-access

We're building a database to capture certain information and struggling past the following;

We have a combo box that has 3 options within it and each of these 3 options, needs to have has it's own financial value attached to it.

So for e.g.;

```
SELECT benefits.[care (dla)],
   Iif([care (dla)] = hrc, 79.15, Iif([care (dla)] = mrc, 51, Iif(
                                  [care (dla)] = lrc, 21, 0))) AS
   [Care (DLA) Award]
FROM   benefits;
```

As you can see, the 3 options within the combo box are;

HRC, MRC and LRC.

Then for e.g. HRC needs to have 79.15 attached to it, so when the database is actually being filled in via our Form submission process the database entry clerk would select HRC.

Once this is selected, the database would know through any resultant queries, that if HRC is chosen, it also has to have 79.15 included in resulting query.

This would then be the same for the other two combo box contents, with their own monetary value as outlined in the HRC first example.

I have a niggling suspicion that the reason when running the above current query, it's just cycling through the 3 options come what may, is because we don't have an if else included and therefore it just keeps going till it finds the end of the query?

I hope the above makes sense, it does to me but hopefully some of you can pick this up and I would be very appreciative of any guidance you can offer in the above regard.

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a reference table that maps the character codes to the numeric values.

```
care_dla  amount
--------  ------
hrc        79.15
mrc        51.00
lrc        21.00
```

Not only will this be more convenient, but if the numeric values ever change (or if a new character code is added) then you just update the table instead of changing *every* query and report in which you "hard coded" the values.

Once your reference table is in place then you can just get the Combo Box Wizard to create a Combo Box that uses the reference table as its record source.

As for your existing query, if we named the reference table [care_dla_amounts] then your query would be

```sql
SELECT 
    benefits.[care (dla)],
    Nz(care_dla_amounts.amount, 0) AS [Care (DLA) Award]
FROM 
    benefits
    LEFT JOIN
    care_dla_amounts
        ON benefits.[care (dla)] = care_dla_amounts.care_dla
```

Comment: Good afternoon Gord. Firstly thank you for taking the time to reply, it's much appreciated. May I ask, when you say "create a reference table that maps the character codes to the numeric values" and without sounding stupid, do you mean table relationships, including FK's, one to many and all that jazz? I've tried searching the internet as to how to achieve this as a newbie in Access but to no avail at present. If there's any specific resource you can point me towards, it would be appreciated also. I look forward to hearing from you in due course.

Comment: @user3244425 Yes, all of that fun stuff. It's really not very difficult. There is an overview [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/guide-to-table-relationships-HA010120534.aspx).